# simple html php insert mysql problem

Tags: php, html

I am trying to insert som data from html forms into my mySql database server.

Here is my html-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Add events</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="addevents.php" method="post">
        id: <input type="text" name="eventID" />
        <br></br>
        larmkod: <input type="text" name="larmkod" />
        <br></br>
        idArduinoT: <input type="text" name="idArduinoT" />
        <br></br>
        handelse: <input type="text" name="handelse" />
        <br></br>
        tid: <input type="text" name="tid" />
        <br></br>
        rumNr: <input type="text" name="rumNr" />
        <br></br>
        inneboendeNamn: <input type="text" name="inneboendeNamn" />
        <br></br>
        overvakare: <input type="text" name="overvakare" />
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php-code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","humhum","humhum");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con;

$sql="INSERT INTO events (eventID, larmkod, idArduinoT, handelse, tid, rumNr, inneboendeNamn, overvakare)
VALUES
('$_POST[eventID]', '$_POST[larmkod]', '$_POST[idArduinoT]', '$_POST[handelse]', '$_POST[tid]', '$_POST[rumNr]',
    '$_POST[inneboendeNamn]', '$_POST[overvakare]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

I don´t see the problem do you? .. eventID is the primary key.

Comment: Nope, I don't see the problem. You didn't tell us.

Comment: problem- your are open to sql injection attack, you must sanitise your data before putting it in the db

Comment: Yes I know, but I am only using it temp for out school project...

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Whats the problem/error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see... Syntax errors:

```
mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con;
                                 ^ missing )
```

SQL injection errors:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events (eventID, larmkod, idArduinoT, handelse, tid, rumNr, inneboendeNamn, overvakare)
VALUES
('$_POST[eventID]', '$_POST[larmkod]', '$_POST[idArduinoT]', '$_POST[handelse]', '$_POST[tid]', '$_POST[rumNr]',
    '$_POST[inneboendeNamn]', '$_POST[overvakare]')";
```

If any of the form fields contain a `'`, your query statement will be invalid. As well, little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will have a field day with your system.

Comment: you to sir! have a field day with your system!

Comment: PHP should have spit out a syntax error for you if it was the missing `)` causing your problem, which suggests that error reporting is off. That SHOULD be turned on while you're developing

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong ;)

Try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events (eventID, larmkod, idArduinoT, handelse, tid, rumNr, inneboendeNamn, overvakare)
VALUES
('{$_POST['eventID']}', '{$_POST['larmkod']}', '{$_POST['idArduinoT']}', '{$_POST['handelse']}', '{$_POST['tid']}', '{$_POST['rumNr']}',
    '{$_POST['inneboendeNamn']}', '{$_POST['overvakare']}')";
```

Look @ your escaping

And edit

```
mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con;
```

Into

```
mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con);
```

You need to work on your security btw. This is really insecure!

Comment: The `{}` notion on the variables isn't necessary. It's good to use it, but it's not required. `echo "{$array['x']}"` is syntactically identically to `echo "$array[x]"` as far as PHP is concerned for 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: hmm really i thought the $array[x] should be at least $array['x'] with the single quotes since its an associative array in this example

Comment: `echo "$array[x]"` is not syntactically identical.  It attempts to dereference the constant `x`, and raises a notice error if `x` has not been defined.  If you `define('x', 'y')`, then `echo "$array[x]"` ends up producing the same output as `echo "$array['y']"`

Comment: Inside double-quoted strings, array keys don't need to be quoted. It's a PHP quirk. But, if you use a 2+ dimensional array, then the `{}` notation is necessary. PHP's parser isn't greedy and will only snag the first dimension. `echo "$array[1][2]"` will be parsed as `echo $array[1], "[2]"`, so you have to say `echo "{$array[1][2]}"`.

Comment: @marc and that's exactly why it's good practice to use `"{$array[1]}"` even when it isn't strictly necessary.  It makes it absolutely clear to others reading your code what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events (eventID, larmkod, idArduinoT, handelse, tid, rumNr, inneboendeNamn, overvakare)
VALUES
('$_POST[eventID]', '$_POST[larmkod]', '$_POST[idArduinoT]', '$_POST[handelse]', '$_POST[tid]', '$_POST[rumNr]',
    '$_POST[inneboendeNamn]', '$_POST[overvakare]')";
```

Each one of those references to POST is somewhat ambiguous, and raises a notice-level error due to the unquoted string.  Less ambiguous syntax:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events (eventID, larmkod, idArduinoT, handelse, tid, rumNr, inneboendeNamn, overvakare)
VALUES
('{$_POST['eventID']}', '{$_POST['larmkod']}', '{$_POST['idArduinoT']}', '{$_POST['handelse']}', '{$_POST['tid']}', '{$_POST['rumNr']}',
    '{$_POST['inneboendeNamn']}', '{$_POST['overvakare']}')";
```

However, this will still result in a SQL error, or even worse, SQL injection should any value contain a `'` char (among others).  These values should, at a minimum, be run through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Alternately, used parameterized queries.

If there are other issues, your best bet will be turning up your error logging, and tailing the relevant log file.  Your apache error_log may be a good place to start.

Also consider running php -l to detect parse-time errors (runtime errors still won't turn up until runtime, however)